# How to parse Table from Wikipedia using htmltab package?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

All,
I am trying to parse 1 table located  here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population#Sovereign_states_and_dependencies_by_population. And I would like to use htmltab package to achieve this task. Currently my code looks like following. However I am getting below Error. I tried passing "Rank", "% of world population " in which function, but still received an error. I am not sure, what could be wrong ?

Please Note: I am new to R and Webscraping, if you could provide explanation of the code, that will be great help.

```
url3 <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population#Sovereign_states_and_dependencies_by_population"
list_of_countries<- htmltab(doc = url3, which = "//th[text() = 'Country(or dependent territory)']/ancestor::table")

Error: Couldn't find the table. Try passing (a different) information to the which argument.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an XPath problem not an R problem. If you inspect the HTML of that table the relevant header is

```
<th class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">
  Country<br><small>(or dependent territory)</small>
</th>
```

So `text()` on this is just "Country".

For example this could work (this is not the only option, you will just have to try out various xpath selectors to see).

```
htmltab(doc = url3, which = "//th[text() = 'Country']/ancestor::table")
```

Alternatively it's the first table on the page, so you could try `which=1` instead.

(NB in Chrome you can do `$x("//th[text() = 'Country']")` and so on in the developer console to try these things out, and no doubt in other browsers also)

Comment: Great. Thanks! For your efforts and time